# Data binding in DataTemplate of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a list box defined as below in xaml:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                     <Ellipse Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                         <ContentPresenter/>
                  </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Text" Text="{Binding IsSelected}"> </TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I want to bind some property of tb_Text (say text property) to some property of the datacontext of the listbox (IsSelected property in this example). Is there a way to achieve that?

**Note:** IsSelected property is coming from the templated parent which has this listbox defined in it's Template.

Comment: and  it is not working in `Text Block`?  
`{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"`

Comment: It doesn't. Maybe because its not a templated child of the main custom control which has this ListBox defined in its template. Anyway, using elementname seems to be working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ElementName` and binding to the `Visibility` property of the `Ellipse` does the trick.